# How can I match Portuguese license plates in a single regular expression?

Tags: regex

I was building a regex to validate Portuguese license plates however, the old ones come in a different format, and I would like to know if it is possible to validate all of the possibilities with just one regex?

These are the possibilities, any other is invalid (i.e.: 00-A0-00):

- 00-00-AA
- AA-00-00
- 00-AA-00

At the moment, I only have this working:

> `([A-Z]){2}-([0-9]){2}-([0-9]){2}`

Comment: "I got this working", then get the other two working as well (hint: they are *very* similar) and then concatenate them into one Big RegEx.

Comment: Nice, but I can't figure it out. Could you help please? I'm doing tests at regexr.com without success :(

Comment: for year >= 2020 compatible plates look [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58993381/860099)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```
((?:[A-Z]{2}-\d{2}-\d{2})|(?:\d{2}-[A-Z]{2}-\d{2})|(?:\d{2}-\d{2}-[A-Z]{2}))
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/nE3oY4/1)

Anchors are better (with `m` flag):

```
(^(?:[A-Z]{2}-\d{2}-\d{2})|(?:\d{2}-[A-Z]{2}-\d{2})|(?:\d{2}-\d{2}-[A-Z]{2})$)
```

[Demo 2](http://regex101.com/r/nE3oY4/2)

Answer (score 3):

### Just Use Alternation

Depending on your regex engine, you may have to vary a few things, but in general the easiest thing to do is to simply provide three alternations. For example:

```
\d{2}-\d{2}-[[:alpha:]]{2}|[[:alpha:]]{2}\d{2}-\d{2}|\d{2}-[[:alpha:]]{2}-\d{2}
```

This works fine for me in Ruby against your sample inputs. YMMV.

Comment: Adding anchors will be better.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte You're bike-shedding. This answer fully addresses the OP's corpus. If you'd like to build the perfect regex that will accept any pathological input, feel free, but it's outside the scope of the original question.

Comment: Missed the chapter about alternation :)

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can always OR the 3 of them

```
([A-Z]){2}-(\d){2}-(\d){2}|(\d){2}-([A-Z]){2}-(\d){2}|(\d){2}-(\d){2}-([A-Z]){2}
```

Answer (score 2):

Now we have in Portugal a new combination AA-00-AA
https://www.razaoautomovel.com/2020/03/novas-matriculas-em-cirulacao ([English google translated](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=pt&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.razaoautomovel.com%2F2020%2F03%2Fnovas-matriculas-em-cirulacao))(started at 2 de march of 2020, you can see the [official law](https://dre.pt/application/conteudo/128071719))

Using [dawg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298607/dawg) answer now is

```
(^(?:[A-Z]{2}-\d{2}-\d{2})|(?:\d{2}-[A-Z]{2}-\d{2})|(?:\d{2}-\d{2}-[A-Z]{2})|(?:[A-Z]{2}-\d{2}-[A-Z]{2})$)
```

Comment: In this question you're not considering the Diplomatc licence plates in Portugal. Here is the format where X stands for a number and the other are fixed letters.
XXX-CDXXX and XXX-FMXXX.

Answer (score 1):

for that new Portugal plate combination I made this one:

```
/([A-Z]{2}|[0-9]{2})-([A-Z]{2}|[0-9]{2})-([A-Z]{2}|[0-9]{2})/gm
```

tested in: [regex101](https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Would it be easier to create another REGEX for Diplomatic licence plates in Portugal and test the 2 conditions or to change the Regex above to consider this plates. Here is the format where X stands for a number and the other are fixed letters. XXX-CDXXX and XXX-FMXXX.

Comment: (^(?:[A-Z]{2}-\d{2}-\d{2})|(?:\d{2}-[A-Z]{2}-\d{2})|(?:\d{2}-\d{2}-[A-Z]{2})|(?:[A-Z]{2}-\d{2}-[A-Z]{2})|(\d{3}-CD\d{3})|(\d{3}-FM\d{3})$)
The last two groups... Of course exists many special variants...